# I want to create a table with "WITH CHECK OPTION"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table STAFF
(StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
fName   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
lname   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone       varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Gender      char(01),
DoB         date    NOT NULL,
Mentor      TINYINT,
Payment_ID  TINYINT NOT NULL,
constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID),
constraint staff_fk foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID),
constraint mentor_fk foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID)
```

For the Gender column I want to insert ONLY 'M','F','O' characters only.
How can I do with this the "WITH CHECK OPTION"

Comment: @GurV Also an option for check constraints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: @SqlZim - This clearly not the OP intention. Please rollback.

Comment: @SqlZim - too much :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz  I would rather leave the question and text as OP wrote it, so OP can clarify rather than cut parts out.

Comment: @SqlZim - O.K., no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want `with check option`.  You want a `check` *constraint*:

```
alter table staff
    add constraint chk_staff_gender check (gender in ('M', 'F', 'O'));
```

(You can put this in the `create table` statement as well.)

`with check option` is an option on views that ensures that data remains consistent even when the data in underlying tables changes (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)) .

Answer (score 1):

add `, constraint gender_chk check (Gender in ('M','F','O'))`

the **with check** option is on by default.

```
create table STAFF
(StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
fName   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
lname   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone       varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Gender      char(01),
DoB         date    NOT NULL,
Mentor      TINYINT,
Payment_ID  TINYINT NOT NULL,
constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID)
constraint staff_fk foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID),
constraint mentor_fk foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID)
, constraint gender_chk check (Gender in ('M','F','O')) 
)
```

From the [MSDN Documentation for `ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) (emphasis added):

> WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK 
>   Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled FOREIGN KEY or CHECK constraint. If not specified, **WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints**, and WITH NOCHECK is assumed for re-enabled constraints.
>
> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK. We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be evaluated in all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the constraint.
>
> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined WITH NOCHECK. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled by using ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to [check constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190377.aspx)

```
create table STAFF
(StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
fName   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
lname   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone       varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Gender      char(01) NOT NULL,
DoB         date    NOT NULL,
Mentor      TINYINT,
Payment_ID  TINYINT NOT NULL,
constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID),
constraint staff_fk foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID),
constraint mentor_fk foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID),
constraint Gender_ck check (Gender in ('M','F','O'))
)
```

---

"WITH CHECK OPTION" is an optional clause for of a [view definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)
Any attempt to update/insert a record, through the view, that cannot be selected by the view, will raise an error.

Comment: `with check` and `with nocheck` are options for check constraints. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: @SqlZim - which is different from "WITH CHECK OPTION", the exact term used by the OP